# What does this tail and head mean in performance's network panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I'm trying to improve the performance of my website with chrome devtools, with the performance panel, I saw the network sequence with line in the front and in the end of request, what does these lines mean? Or any document could also help.